# Visual Studio version required for WCF development

Tags: wcf, visual-studio-2010

I'm starting on a project which involves som WCF development. I looking at buying Visual Studio, but I'm not quiet sure which veresion is required for WCF development.

Is Visual Studio Pro sufficient?

Regards,
Steffen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, any version of Visual Studio 2010 (or 2008, for that matter) is acceptable for WCF development.  (WCF is an API, not a Visual Studio "feature")